# How to make <table></table> evenly display different items?

Tags: html, css

I made a simple table with HTML and CSS, however, the items don't display evenly when you resize your browser.

Screenshot:

[image: click this]

As you can see, there is a lot of empty space.

How can I made it so these three rows evenly display across the div box no matter how the user resizes the browser?

I made a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/5nm9m9pL/ (looks fine until your stretch the browser)

Code:
HTML

```
<div class="bet-ids" id="bet-ids">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Profit</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bitcoincryptopro</td>
            <td>232</td>
            <td>+0.32423</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bitcoincryptopro</td>
            <td>523</td>
            <td>+0.32423</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bitcoincryptopro</td>
            <td>4352</td>
            <td>+0.32423</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bitcoincryptopro</td>
            <td>5234</td>
            <td>+0.32423</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bet-ids {
        height: auto;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 60%;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue;
        color: black;

        background-color: white;
    }
```

Comment: When working with percentages you should have a parent Element that has a static width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "lots of white space" you mean you want to center it, then you can just add `margin: auto` to both the `table` and the `div`, since your `div` has a fixed width of 60%

Otherwise if you mean that you want to stretch out the table, then obviously you can't have a width of 60%;

```css
.bet-ids {
        height: auto;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 60%;
        margin:auto;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue;
        color: black;

        background-color: white;
    }
    
 table {
  margin: auto;
 }
```

```html
<div class="bet-ids" id="bet-ids">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Profit</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bitcoincryptopro</td>
            <td>232</td>
            <td>+0.32423</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bitcoincryptopro</td>
            <td>523</td>
            <td>+0.32423</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bitcoincryptopro</td>
            <td>4352</td>
            <td>+0.32423</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bitcoincryptopro</td>
            <td>5234</td>
            <td>+0.32423</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I added .table{ margin:auto; }, though space still persistent. http://prntscr.com/go4xye

Comment: Is your actual data/html format different? Because if you look at my snippet, you will see it doesn't have that problem. Maybe you have some other conflicting css as well.

Comment: Hi, I use google chrome inspect element tool , and made discovery conflict code caused it . thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.bet-ids table {width: 100%;}` to your CSS: Tables set their width by their content unless you tell them otherwise.